# How to cite one volume of a book which has been published in different volumes (APA 7)?

Tags: citations, citation-style

How to cite one volume of book which has been published in different volumes, **following the APA 7 guidelines**?

Imagine the 3 volumes of the book *Quantum Theory of Fields* by Steven Weinberg were published, by Cambridge University Press, the same year, say 1995.

How are we suppose to write the in-text citation?
How are we suppose to write the citation in the bibliography section?

I have consulted many website and other documents in multiple languages and I am not able to find the recommendation for this situation.

https://elementary.oslis.org/secondary/cite-sources/apa/apa-citation-examples/other-visual-works-citation-examples-for-apa-7

https://libguides.umgc.edu/apa-examples

https://libguides.usc.edu/APA7th/intextcitations

https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/in_text_citations_author_authors.html

https://bibliotheque.hesav.ch/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/GuideAPA7_Sante-Travail_social_HES-SO_2020.pdf

https://www.cogitatiopress.com/doc/APA%20Style%20Guide%20(7th%20ed.).pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APA Style blog entry on [How to Cite Edition, Volume, and Page Numbers for Books](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2018/09/how-to-cite-edition-volume-and-page-numbers-for-books.html) provides

> In a reference to a whole book, cite the edition and volume numbers—separated by a comma—but do not cite a page range.
>
> Here are some templates for citing print versions of books that include edition and volume numbers:
>
> **Authored Book**
>
> Author, A. A. (Year). Title of book (xx ed., Vol. xx). Location: Publisher.
>
> **Edited Book**
>
> Editor, E. E. (Ed.). (Year). Title of book (xx ed., Vol. xx). Location: Publisher.

Note that the blog post linked above was posted in 2018 and makes reference to the sixth edition of the APA Publication Manual. [As of APA 7 the location is no longer required to be included](https://apastyle.apa.org/blog/publisher-locations-in-book-references), so we can simplify the format to

> Author, A. A. (Year). Title of book (xx ed., Vol. xx). Publisher.

For some kind of completeness, it's worth noting that the [first link](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2018/09/how-to-cite-edition-volume-and-page-numbers-for-books.html) also states

> Some publishers title each volume of a multivolume work. In this case, include the volume number within the title when constructing your reference instead of citing it parenthetically.

but this appears irrelevant in your case, as Weinberg's QFT books have subtitles for the volumes, but do not have individual top-level titles.

---

Now, turning to your specific example:

> Imagine the 3 volumes of the book Quantum Theory of Fields by Steven Weinberg were published, by Cambridge University Press, the same year, say 1995.

OK... Officially, they were published [1995](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139644167), [1996](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139644174) and [2000](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139644198), respectively, but we can make this assumption if you want. (And my copy of vol. 2 actually does say it was first published in 1995.)

> How are we suppose to write the in-text citation? How are we suppose to write the citation in the bibliography section?

In case you're citing a single volume, the in-text citation would be like any other: "(Weinberg, 1995)" or "Weinberg (1995)", depending on whether you use the parenthetical or narrative form. The bibliography would have, for example

Weinberg, S. (1995). The Quantum Theory of Fields (Vol. 1). Cambridge University Press.

---

If you want to cite two of the volumes *and* assume they were published the same year, use the usual format with letters, *i.e.* "Weinberg (1995a)", "Weinberg (1995b)", etc.

If you want to cite specific pages in all three volumes it's best to provide three separate references. However, if a more compact citation is desired, there is the option of a ["whole anthology citation"](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/09/how-to-cite-an-anthology-or-collected-works.html), *e.g.*, "(Weinberg, 1995-2005)" in-text, and with bibliography item:

Weinberg, S. (1995-2000). The Quantum Theory of Fields (Vols. 1-3). Cambridge University Press.